# undefined method `has_selector?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) cucumber (capybara) step

Tags: cucumber, response, capybara, null

I would appreciate some help with the following problem.

When I run my cucumber (using capybara) feature using

```
rake cucumber:wip
```

I get the following error: (ie the response object is not defined for some reason)

```
  Then I should be able to see 1 announcement # features/step_definitions/view_announcements_steps.rb:8
      undefined method `has_selector?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/view_announcements_steps.rb:10:in `/^I should be able to see (\d+) announcement$/'
      features/view_announcements.feature:13:in `Then I should be able to see 1 announcement'
```

I have the following cucumber feature file:

```
@wip
    Feature: User views announcements
    As a user
    I want to be able to view announcements
    So that I am up-to-date with the latest news

Background:
    Given there is 1 announcement

Scenario: I am not logged in
    Given I am not logged in
    When I go to main
    Then I should be able to see 1 announcement 

Scenario: I am logged in 
    Given I am logged in as "test/password"
    When I go to main
    Then I should be able to see 1 announcement
```

and step definitions:

```
Given /^there is|are (\d+) announcement$/ do |arg1|
    arg1.to_i.times do
        Announcement.create!({:title => "Test Announcement",
                                                        :body => "This is a test"})
    end
end

Then /^I should be able to see (\d+) announcement$/ do |arg1|
    response.should have_selector("div#announcement", :count => arg1)
end  

When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end

Given /^I am not logged in$/ do
  visit('/users/sign_out') 
end

Given /^user "([^\/]*)\/([^\"]*)" exists$/ do |username, password|
  User.new(:username => username,
           :password => password,
           :password_confirmation => password).save!
end

Given /^I am logged in as "([^\/]*)([^\"]*)"$/ do |username, password| 
  Given %{user "#{username}/#{password}" exists}
  visit('/users/sign_in')#And %{I go to sign_in}
  And %{I fill in "user_password" with "#{password}"}
  And %{I press "Sign in"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a path was incorrect in features/support/paths.rb.